# How can I ensure that Times New Roman font is used for text in circuitikz and tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, fontspec, circuitikz, ieeetran

I am preparing figures for an IEEEtran journal, and they require that all text in the figures be written in Times New Roman font. I have tried using "**\setmainfont{Times New Roman}**" and "**font=\fontspec{Times New Roman}**" (XeLaTeX) but I'm not sure if that is correct, as I don't have much experience with fonts and LaTeX. I would appreciate it if you could guide me on how to enforce the use of Times New Roman for everything.

I'm also unsure if this requirement applies to math formulas.

> "For consistency throughout the journal, we ask that wording in the
> figures remain in Times New Roman font when possible. Also, make sure
> to use the same font (down to capitalization and style, italics or
> bold) for the variables in your figures as you use in the text of your
> paper"

(Source: https://www.ieee-pels.org/images/files/pdf/TTE/tte-infoauth-fill-3026800-x.pdf)

```
\documentclass[border={0.1mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[american,siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand*{\B}[1]{\ifmmode\bm{#1}\else\textbf{#1}\fi}

% set all label and text to font of 9pt

\ctikzset{bipole label style/.style={font=\fontspec{Times New Roman}\color{black}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}}
\ctikzset{bipole annotation style/.style={font=\fontspec{Times New Roman}\color{black}\ttfamily\large}}
\ctikzset{bipole voltage style/.style={font=\fontspec{Times New Roman}\color{black}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}}
\ctikzset{bipole current style/.style={font=\fontspec{Times New Roman}\color{black}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, 
circuitikz/inductors/thickness=0.9,
circuitikz/capacitors/thickness=0.9,
circuitikz/power supplies/thickness=0.9,
circuitikz/sources/thickness=0.9,
circuitikz/switches/thickness=0.9,
circuitikz/grounds/thickness=0.9,
font=\color{black}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
]

\draw  (2, 2.4) to [short,o-] ++(0.1,0) to [cute inductor, v^=$\bm{V_\mathrm{L}}$, voltage/american label distance=0.6pt,name =L] ++ (1.8,0) to [short, -o] ++(0.1,0);


% draw input and output
\draw (-0.3,0.4) to [V] (-0.3,2.4) to [short] ++(1.3,0) ; 
\node [above ] at (-0.3,2.4)  {$\B{V_\mathrm{DC}}$};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure they are ok with `xelatex`? Anyway, `circuitikz` use the current font for the document... at least it should. So if you set the main font *and* the math font to be the correct one for the document, simply *do nothing* for `circuitikz`.

Comment: @Rmano I see, thank you. I thought that `pdflatex` and `xelatex` just different engine to produce the same PDF?

Comment: in a sense, yes, but especially the approach to fonts is wildly different (much more modern in xe- and lualatex)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good practice that if you want/have to follow a publisher-provided class, to use it and not change their default¹. So the best approach is simply to use the class itself and *avoid touching font definitions*:

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEconf}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
Text V\textsubscript{x}, math $V_x$,
    \tikz[american, baseline=(Rvoltage.base)]
    \draw(0,0) to[R, v=$V_x$, name=R] ++(2,0);
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, `circuitikz` just goes with the flow  and uses whatever math or text font is current.

Now, if you want to prepare the figure separately, it's handy to use `standalone`, and in that case you may need to tinker a bit with the fonts. In `IEEEconf.cls`, they use

```
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}
\RequirePackage{helvet}
\RequirePackage{courier}
```

So you can just do the same like this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx, helvet, courier}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american]
   \draw(0,0) to[R, v=$V_x$, name=R] ++(2,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(The two images are copied and pasted with the same scale, and it seems they match; `IEEEconf` is based on a 10-points `article` class).

---

¹ which can be not so nice, mind you, or current...

Comment: Thank you for the advice. How would you set the font size for label or node?

Comment: @emnha, globally or locally? The default font size is the document's one. You can use the global `\small`, `\large`, etc.,  or the `font` key of the nodes. But probably this is another question, isn't it? Try to prepare an MWE for your problem and pose another question, please.